# Where do I find the tables that a role has access to in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to use the System Tables to fetch some metadata about the whole Vertica cluster at a table level (including permissions).

Where can I find the information about permissions required to SELECT on a table?

I've poked around in the `GRANTS` and `ROLES` system tables, but I can't find any role->table mapping.

I considered using `HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE()` but that does it on user level. I'd rather do it at the role level.

Comment: What is your desired result? [This may help](http://datadug.com/how-to-script-out-users-roles-and-permissions-in-vertica/)

Comment: I've actually found the answer (it's in the `GRANTS` table). I wasn't able to view them previously because I didn't have the required permissions. I can't post an answer though, because I can't answer my own question for 8 hours.

Comment: But you said you *"poked around"* in the `GRANTS` table...

Comment: Yeah, the result was one row which contained the role I was assigned to, which led me to believe only roles would be present in the `GRANTS` table. I hadn't created any tables at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM grants ORDER BY grantor, grantee;
```

The `privileges_description` column shows the privilege types, such as (in your case) `SELECT`.  (If you only want the SELECTs, you can refine that query.)

Source: [Viewing Privileges Granted on Objects](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Security/DBUsersAndPrivileges/ViewingPrivilegesGrantedOnObjects.htm) in the Admin Guide.  (That's from the documentation for version 7.1.x.)

Answer (score 0):

you can view the privileges for user with following command. 
SELECT * FROM grants where grantee='u_uat_Logging';
-- here 
SELECT * FROM grants where grantee='uat_ccPlatform_Logging_readonly';

Answer (score 0):

**Privileges view for User**

You can view the privileges which are assigned to user directly for user with following command:

```
-- here u_uat_Logging is the name of the User
SELECT * FROM grants where grantee='u_uat_Logging';
```

Privileges view for Role

You can view the privileges which is assigned using the role , for user with following command:

```
-- here uat_ccPlatform_Logging_readonly is the name of the Role
SELECT * FROM grants where grantee='uat_ccPlatform_Logging_readonly';
```

**Other important tables to view the information**

1. `users` - to view the user info
2. `grants` - to view the user's privileges
3. `roles` - to view the roles
4. `client_auth` - to view the authentications(IP restriction/allowed IP access)
5. `resource_pools` - to view the resources pool info